# .NET Core Integration Tests with SpecFlow using Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: .net-core, specflow, visual-studio-mac

We have a .NET Core app that implements a series of REST APIs, we have integration tests that call each API and validates the response.

We'd like to be able to use feature files with the tests so that they act as documentation for the API itself. We've been looking at using SpecFlow but we are doing the development for the application using Visual Studio for Mac and all the examples of how to get this working are Windows based.

Is this supported on Visual Studio for Mac? The sticking point seems to be that the Windows examples rely on the Visual Studio extension that isn't available for Mac.

Comment: This is interesting, because the plugin for Visual Studio basically gives you some extra menu items and new item templates. NuGet packages do the parsing at build time, so I think you could get something to work if you know what to put in the .csproj files.

Comment: Have you tried installing the `SpecFlow` and `SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation` NuGet packages to one of your test projects? I'm looking in the .csproj file for a .NET Core/MS Test project, and I'm not seeing anything special. Try installing those two packages, then create a .feature file with some sample Gherkin (you'll need to do it manually as a text file at first) and see if building the solution creates a .feature.cs file.

Comment: See also: https://support.specflow.org/hc/en-us/community/posts/360012011377--SpecFlow-Visual-Studio-Mac-Support

Answer (score 0):

I have now managed to get this working to some degree using the NuGet packages mentioned in the comments to my question and the Straight8 extension for Visual Studio for Mac.